# What is wrong with AES-CTR-HMAC-SHA256 - or why is it not in TLS?

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation, tls, ctr

It seems the only specified CTR mode ciphers in TLS are all GCM based.

GCM ciphers run `AES-CTR` and do authenticated encryption with a MAC based on Galois-field arithmetic ("GHASH") - and the latter seems to be difficult to get right in software (side-channel attacks, constant time) or require CPU hardware support (e.g. Intel AES-NI / PCLMULQDQ) which in turn might be manipulated/weakened via microcode updates/implants.

On the other hand `HMAC-SHA256` seems relatively simple to do right in software and when used together with AES-CTR and a encrypt-then-MAC scheme.

So why are there no modes like `TLS_DHE_RSA_AES128_SHA256`?

The closest I could find is [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ctr-01) unfinished, expired IETF draft.

Comment: Perhaps because `SHA256` is unacceptably slow - think 13 cycles/byte minimum (on top of the encryption cost).

Comment: Well, `AES-CBC-(HMAC)-SHA256` has that too, doesn't it? And `SHA1` is less secure. And then you could have a `AES-CTR-(HMAC)-SHA1` also. And the alternative of `AEAD` like `AES-GCM` is very new and not yet widely available.

Comment: I guess the reason may be both AES CTR and GMAC can be computed in parallel and as you state both can be hardware accelerated by many modern CPUs - not a drawback. In fact, the peak AES throughput with these instruction sets often can only be realised with at least 8 blocks computed at once to hide instruction latency. CTR-HMAC-SHA256 doesn't have the same performance characteristics (with either CTR or CBC it would be dominated by the HMAC processing time). So why add CTR-HMAC at all, it doesn't seem to add anything that GCM doesn't already do quicker.

Comment: For reasons other than mere performance, e.g. simpler to get right in software without side-channel attack vectors. Also the principle cipher seems to be around longer than GCM. I am just wondering: why hasn't that RFC been finished years ago?

Comment: Well they had the opportunity to fix the MAC record format in TLS1.2 to remove the padding oracle completely (either by MACing the padding or moving to a EtA model), they didn't (which would be a far better solution in my view). Other than that I don't see your objection to CBC + HMAC as TLS1.1 onwards uses an explicit IV.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:**

There would be nothing (that isn't already wrong with TLS) necessarily wrong with a CTR + HMAC cipher suite, but the technical merits are only one factor in a technical feature getting to RFC status in the TLS working group.

Without being discourteous to the [TLS Working Group (WG)](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/tls/charter/) participants or process, other reasons can be: political (including national/standards body alignment); personal/corporate preference/motivation; historical timing; resistance to change (modifying implementations is an often-cited cost); fear/uncertainty/doubt/apathy/debating skills etc.
TLS standardization happens very much in a real world implementation + real humans interacting environment, where the isolated technical merits of an idea are by no means the only measure of, or contributing factor to, success.

Why the draft-ietf-tls-ctr in particular never made it to RFC status (as part of TLS 1.2 or separately) is a little murkier, but my best guess is that a combination of:

- **timing and politics:** probably most importantly, AEAD modes such as GCM, many based on CTR mode, and in the case of GCM favoured by a NIST standardisation process, came along early in the TLS 1.2 process and probably supplanted CTR in the thinking of the WG editors/participants.
- **uncertainty:** CTR in 2006 was relatively less known and trusted compared to CBC.
- **doubt:** there were some concerns stated in the TLS WG discussions about its use in DTLS and with explicit vs implicit IVs
- Eric Rescorla was both an author for draft-ietf-tls-ctr and co-editor of the TLS 1.2 draft, so I suspect once GCM became a preference for the WG he stopped editing and pushing the CTR mode.

**Longer timeline:**

- Nov 2005

First mentions of draft-ietf-tls-ctr at [Oct 2005 TLS WG meeting](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/64/tls.html), at this stage not a chartered WG item.

- Feb 2006

[draft-ietf-tls-ctr 00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ctr-00) begins life as a companion draft to the [TLS 1.2 draft 00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-rfc4346-bis-00).

- March 2006

draft-ietf-tls-ctr is listed on the [March 2006 TLS WG meeting](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/65/tls.html) agenda
The TLS WG charter at that time explicitly discusses counter mode cipher suites as being a goal of TLS 1.2.

The [March 2006 TLS WG meeting minutes](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/65/minutes/tls.html) refer to draft-ietf-tls-ctr as being a chartered item and ready for review.

At this point the *First draft of TLS 1.2 specification, including CTR mode cipher suites* milestone is marked as *Done* but CTR modes are clearly not in [draft 1.2 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-rfc4346-bis-00) at that time (or any other).

- July 2006

At the [July 2006 TLS WG meeting](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/66/tls.html) draft-ietf-tls-ctr is described as ready for last call in the [minutes](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/66/minutes/tls.txt).

No last call for draft-ietf-tls-ctr eventuates on the TLS WG mailing list.

- October 2006

[TLS 1.2 draft 02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-rfc4346-bis-02) is published, and AEAD/GCM modes are included for the first time.

- November 2006

At the [Nov 2006 TLS WG meeting](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/67/tls.html) draft-ietf-tls-ctr is still on the agenda, and [the minutes](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/67/minutes/tls.txt) show discussion centered around the counter and IV structure.  A GCM mode draft is mentioned as being imminent.

- December 2006

Some concerns about counter mode, in particular counter/IV structures, are discussed on [TLS WG mailing list](ftp://ftp.ietf.org/ietf-mail-archive/tls/2006-12.mail).

- January 2007

Discussion of CTR mode on the [TLS WG mailing list](ftp://ftp.ietf.org/ietf-mail-archive/tls/2007-01.mail) has dried up apart from some discussion about potential issues with DTLS, and GCM mode is being actively discussed.

- March 2007

draft-ietf-tls-ctr is still mentioned in the TLS 1.2 charter, but no longer on the [March 2007 TLS WG meeting agenda](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/68/tls.html), and all discussion in [the minutes](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/68/minutes/tls.txt) is about GCM.

From this point on draft-ietf-tls-ctr is not mentioned again, and no CTR modes end up in TLS 1.2. GCM modes go on to be published in [RFC 5288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288) about the same time as TLS 1.2 is finalised in [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).

Comment: Thanks for collecting historical traces! The list of non-technical reasons (for non-existance of more TLS CTR) you give is compelling. Too bad;(